# Can I specify an absolute location for UDF_Modules within xlwings?

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm using xlwings to expose python functions as user defined functions within Excel.  It works perfectly if the excel file is in the same directory as the .py file which contains my UDF functions.

I would like to save my Excel file anywhere and just update my xlwings.conf file to have the location of the python module which contains the udf definitions.

If I set the conf file to have

"UDF MODULES","C:\src\xlwings_wrapper\xlwings_udfs"

I get the following error ModuleNotFound: No module named 'C:\src\xlwings_wrapper\xlwings_udfs'.  How ever I have checked and the xlwings_udfs.py file is in that location.

Does anyone know if setting an absolute path for the UDF Modules is supported by xlwings?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#global-settings) where the settings are explained: The `UDF_MODULES` only accept the module name. The path to where the modules are is set (and explained) under `PYTHONPATH`. So in your example you have to set the following:

```
"UDF MODULES","name_of_module"
"PYTHONPATH","C:\src\xlwings_wrapper\xlwings_udfs"
```

Comment: Thank you Felix.

I've realised my mistake was that I assumed UDF_MODULES was a file path to the module, instead it's a module path.  So if pythonpath is c:\src I can put UDF_MODULES of xlwings_wrapper.xlwings_udfs

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it solves your problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake. Should have read the manual

For completeness, when using either the xlwings.conf sheet or the UDF module box on the ribbon you need to adopt this setting configuration.